# how to catch the values of multiple xpath from a search result and iterate them?

Tags: java, selenium, for-loop, xpath, switch-statement

I am a newbie here, this is my very first question:

On amazon.com, insert a keyword of 'stamps' and click search button, I got millions of results and amazon display 15 results on each page, a number right next to the 5 stars is the customer review for each stamp product, 
for instance, the first stamp product has 140 customer reviews, it is a xpath value, I want to capture the 15 xpath values on the first page and iterate them. how can I do that? 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: For instance: the first stamp product's xpath is .//*[@id='result_0']/div/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/a, the second one is .//*[@id='result_1']/div/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/a, and so on.

Comment: the first span is as follow: <a class="a-size-small a-link-normal a-text-normal" href="https://www.amazon.com/Coastal-Postcard-Forever-Postage-USPS/dp/B012W3MBMM/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1477450413&sr=8-1&keywords=stamps#customerReviews">140</a>

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code,

```
List<String> itemsReviewCount = new ArrayList<String>();
for(WebElement items: driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".a-fixed-left-grid-col.a-col-right"))){
//below condition is to skip the sponsored items. Comment this, if you want to retrieve the sponsored items as well
if(items.findElements(By.xpath("//h5[text()='Sponsored']")).size() > 0)
   continue;
itemsReviewCount.add(items.findElement(By.cssSelector("span+.a-size-small.a-link-normal.a-text-normal")).getText());            
}
```

This code will retrieve the Customer review count of the 15 items that are being displayed (excluding the sponsored items displayed below)

Comment: Thank you so much for prompt reply, let me implement it into my code. :)